# How can i find this Hashing Algorithm?

Tags: hash, import, google-cloud-firestore, azure-sql-database

So hi, i have a String that is saved as a hash on an Azure SQL DB, but i can't seem to find out in which Algorithm it is saved, we want to Migrate our Users to a Firestore DB but we apparently need the Algorithm for the First Login.

Hashed String: **VxfCosOIw7PDrsOqw78YwqtCwoxUK8KCwpVkw5LCn0hcf8OgZsKEwpTDqSvDmMOMwql+**

Original String: **Drag2311**

Salt: **+2zPSiLUCzdASr3dS1fRrH6vxEAU6/V4kr/73uVmRoo=**

I've seen on other posts that people asked for the Original String, so i just posted all relevant information that i have, and hope that someone can help me.

**EDIT**: I have checked the code and couldn't find anything related to Hashing, and am relatively sure that it is Server Encryption. Its a CMK and a CEK, but i still have a hard time to find a way to look up the set Algorithm.

Comment: could you share the code hashing the users in the database? either the sql with the sql hash call, or the hash in whatever programming language you are using. Otherwise you would have flag all users not yet migrated in the new system, when they log in after the migration, if they have a flag, authenticate the user against the old db, and then migrate them to the new, clearing the flag afterwards.

Comment: @JoSSte our new app has no connection to the sql db and i don't know the code used to create the hashing in those columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that i need to know the keys of the Column in MS SQL Column Encrytion, so i either have to contact the ones that set it or the Azure Support.

So rather than doing it like that, im just going to do it rather ineffectively, by migrating the data of those accounts but not the accounts themselves.

In the Firebase Functions i will define that on a new account create it should check if the email exists in a json object with the email and userid, and if it exists then it will just hook the relating userid with the old data to that account, rather than creating a new set of datas.

Thanks for your time and i noticed that i should have done it this way before.

Comment: you can accept(mark)  it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.